# Equivalent system for a shaft driven by a belt

Tags: statics

I have a pulley, rigidly connected to a shaft (supported by bearings which don't restrict rotation about x), which is driven by an input pulley of the same dimensions through a belt drive. Forces are transmitted from the input pulley to the belt and then from the belt back to the output pulley. The tight side of the belt is the one with the higher tension force. [image]

The two tension forces can be replaced by equivalent force system, which consists of a force passing through the center point of the pulley and an applied moment. Does the force acting at the middle point only have a y component? Since the force transmitted between the belt and the pully is distributed along half of its side face shouldn't there also be a z component? [image]

Answer (score 0):

As long as the friction between the pully and the Belt is is greater than the slip force, and we can ignore secondary small frictions of bearings, etc, the shaft of the pully gets loaded with a turque equal to

$$\tau_{1}*r{_1}= \tau_2*r_2$$
In this case equal to driving shaft torque because they are the same size.

- $\tau_1$ = torque at the driven pully
- $\tau_2$ = Torque at the driver pully
- r = radius of the pully

The torque at the Pully then converts to tension at the belt, this is in addition to the the pretension already set in the belt.
$$T= \tau_1/r_1$$

Comment: I'm primarly interested in the radial force acting at the pulley's center; isn't the torque at the pulley due to the pretension?

Comment: no. pretension causes shear and bending moment at the shaft. say you have Ft as pretension. it creates Ft/area of shaft shear anf Ft acting on the shaft as a simply supported beam causing bending moment.

Answer (score 0):

> since the force transmitted between the belt and the pully is distributed along half of its side face shouldn't there also be a z component?

There are zero forces in the z direction.  The force on the pulley turns into a torque about the x axis.  You're overthinking the forces, keep it simple.